# Запрет отображения картинок для определенных IP

Tags: .htaccess

Как можно для определенных IP запретить отображение на сайте картинок? Сделать так чтобы они просто не грузились для их.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно выдавать вместо картинок для запрещенных ip 403 ошибку со своим содержимым. Выдаваемый файл можно пустым сделать.

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://сайт.ru/путь_до_вашего_файла_выдаваемого_пользователю_при_отказе_в_доступе.htm

<FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
  Deny from 127.0.0.1 запрещенные ip
</FilesMatch>
```